# Why is python giving the count of fields in all of the rows in a csv file the same as the row with the max count?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with each row containing a review and each sentence of the review is in a separate column--so each row does not have the same number of columns. I wrote Python code to print out the total number of reviews and sentences, and also the max, min, and avg number of sentences per review. This worked on a small sample (5 rows). However, when I tried a larger csv file (10,000 rows) that I had copied the sample from, the max, min and avg all came out to be 18. I'm thinking maybe that the file is giving all of the rows the same number of columns (sentences) that the largest row has. If that's the case, is there a way to fix this?

Here is my code in case I've made a mistake in it:

```
import csv

with open('reviews.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    num_sentences = []
    for row in reader:
        num_sentences.append(len(row))

print("Total reviews:", len(num_sentences))
print("Total Sentences:", sum(num_sentences))   
print("Max sentences per review:", max(num_sentences))
print("Min sentences per review:", min(num_sentences))
print("Average sentences per review:", (sum(num_sentences)/(len(num_sentences)))
```

Here is the file I am using:

```
I had her for 2 classes and she was just awful.,Terrible teaching skills and     would have no idea what she was doing.,She'd curve her tests to make up for their poor quality.,"As a person, she was pretty nice but her teaching skills were SERIOUSLY lacking."
I can't believe the retards this woman had to deal with - she's a freakin' saint for having to put up with all of their ****.,Professor Green was very funny and easy to understand - Awesome professor!
Easy A. Boring class.,Find a friend in class so you can keep each other awake.,"The class was so boring, it was almost painful to sit through.","However, it did help me make the Dean's List, since it's nearly impossible to NOT get an A."
Her class is extremely boring and a waste of time.,She does not seem to care about her students.
No Comments
```

Here is the printout for this file:

```
Total reviews: 5
Total sentences: 13
Max sentences per review: 4
Min sentences per review: 1
Average sentences per review: 2.6
```

Comment: How is the code working? You're taking a list `num_sentences` and dividing by a number `len(num_sentences)`. Also give a sample of the data that you're working with.

Comment: I made a small edit  to the code--I forgot I had changed it to try something different. Each len(row) is appended to the list, giving me the number of sentences in each row in the list. So if I were to print num_sentences for the 5 rows, it would be:
>>>[4, 2, 4, 2, 1]

The printout for the above code is:
    >>>
    Total reviews: 5
    Total Sentences: 13
    Max sentences per review: 4
    Min sentences per review: 1
    Average sentences per review: 2.6

Comment: I copied your code and all it's giving me is the number of rows in the file, not sentences.

Comment: I'm sorry, I saw what you were referring to (dividing num_sentences by len) and it should have read sum(num_sentences)--I have edited it.

Comment: I would check the file (10,000 rows), there doesn't seem to be an issue with the actual code. I copied the sample data you gave and replicated it and got everything working fine.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't resolve the issue with the file, so I went back to the original file of reviews that I had tokenized into sentences per column and re-ran in and then I was able to run the code on that file. I think I had copied the csv file to another (in Excel) and that might have caused the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out